# TFS mapping on the working folder is already in use

Tags: tfs

I wanna get a solution from TFS 2013 in VS 2017 but there's an error:
[image: working folder is already in use on TFS]

I've deleted my work space but it didn't work;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find the solution. The only way to resolve this issue is changing the computer name.

Comment: The computer name has nothing to do with the issue.

Answer (score 5):

You need to edit your current workspace and map to another local folder:

Team Explorer > Under Solution click the `Workspace` dropdown arrow > Manage Workspaces... > Select your current workspace  > Edit > Change the local folder to a folder.

---

**UPDATE:**

Did you also delete the local mapped folder? If not you will see the error. So, the workaround is mapping current workspace to a new local folder, or cleaning (delete all the files) the old mapped local folder, then remap current workspace to the old local folder again.

[image: image here]

Comment: @M.Mansoury Did you also delete the local mapped folder? If not you will see the error. So, the workaround is mapping current workspace to a new local folder, or cleaning (delete all the files) the old mapped local folder, then remap current workspace to the old local folder again.

Answer (score 0):

You may list workspaces using command line (With Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt) with the following command:

```
tf workspaces
```

You may delete an existing workspace using command line (With Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt) with the following command:

```
tf workspace /delete WORKSPACENAME /collection:COLLECTION_URL
```

The drawback is that you must have connection to the TFS server or the command would not work.

Don't know how to delete a workspace if the TFS server is not available.

Answer (score 0):

I just renamed the local folder, mapped the workspace to it, did a get latest, then was prompted to 'Resolve Conflicts'.  Selected 'Keep Local File Contents' for all and this created new 'Pending Changes' of my old pending changes from the previous workspace name.